# How to hide header menu while scrolling in drupal

Tags: jquery, html, css, drupal, drupal-7

Hi can anyone help me how to hide header div while scrolling in drupal.

```
<header class="header<?php print theme_get_setting('header_top_menu') && !$one_page ? '' : ' header-two'; ?>">
<div class = "header-wrapper">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 logo-box">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="<?php print url('<front>'); ?>">
       <img src="" class="logo-img" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    </div><!-- .logo-box -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by custom jquery on window.scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){

        if($(window).scrollTop() > 1){
            $('header ul').hide();
        } else{
            $('header ul').show();
        }
    });
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/s4Lpbkqg/2/)**